# Install from VMware Workstation Player screen is cutoff and unable to continue installation

Tags: system-installation, release-odin, virtualization, bugs, live-installation

When trying to install from VMware Workstation Player I am unable to continue with the installer. The resolution is not detected by Elementary OS properly, and this leads to the installer screen being cutoff. None of the buttons on the bottom-right of the screen are clickable. This can lead to a bad first-user experience if they are wanting to try this out in a VM before committing to installing on their PC.

[image: VMware Workstation Player Screenshot]

In Workstation Player I have the monitor resolution set to 1920x1080, however Elementary OS does not detect this properly.

[image: Workstation Player Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/p2zsss/cannot_install_odin_on_virtualbox_because_of/h8nrthu) Reddit comment which seems to fix the issue, however since this doesn't happen with the Ubuntu, Fedora, or Solus installers I would still consider it a bug that Elementary OS should fix. As we are seeing with recent media coverage (LTT), the new user experience on Linux is essential to getting folks to adopt.

Reddit comments content in case it gets deleted at some point:

> I used Workstation Player and wasn't able to enable EFI in the UI, but added a line to the VM file (.vmx), so the first three lines look like this:
>
> ```
> .encoding = "windows-1252"
> config.version = "8"
> firmware="efi"
> ```
>
> Posted by u/3point147ersMorgan